# Is there another option to delete the entity by pk of included entity without using QueryDsl? (

Tags: hibernate, entity, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to delete some entity using entity's pk what included another entity.

It' means, 
I have a Entity named 'A'.
And It has a another Entity B.

And I want delete My A Entity using B's PK.

But I coulden't find some method in **JpaRepository** except by method 'deletByB'.

I don't want to delete my Entity A by using delete By Entitiy.

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<AEtt, Long>{
    void deleteByB(BEtt b);
}
```

---

I found another way.

using QueryDslRepositorySupport.

```
@Repository("BRepository")
public class BExtendRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements BExtendRepository{
public BExtendRepositoryImpl() {
    super(BEtt.class);
}

@Override
public void deleteByAId(long aId) {
    QBEtt b = QBEtt.bEtt;
    JPQLQuery query = from(b);
    query.where(b.a.aId.eq(aId));
}
```

}

---

But I want to use JpaRepository.
Can I delete my Entity by using included Entity's PK with JpaRepository?

I hope get some hint here. Thank you! Have a nice day! :-)

Comment: Which kind of relation do the entities A and B have? One-to-one or one-to-many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your entity A is `Order` and B is `Customer` and they share a one-to-many relationship, where `Order.customer` points to the related customer object and `Customer.id` is the customer's PK,
you should be able to achieve this as follows:

```
@Repository
public OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    Long deleteByCustomer_Id(String id);
}
```

But the underscore is optional.

Comment: Thank for your answer!
I hope you have a nice day! :-)